# Need to filter data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table ldgr with following fields

```
Vchrno    date      debit  credit  amount
JV1    01-mar-19    BA11   0        100
JV1    01-mar-19     0      PE113   100
JV1    01-mar-19    BA33   0         300
JV1    01-mar-19    BA44    0      400
```

I want to filter all JVs with dedit code BA11 and creditcode starting with PE for a particular time period. Only a few JVs having this PE on credit side. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach uses aggregation:

```
SELECT Vchrno
FROM ldgr
WHERE date BETWEEN <date1> AND <date2>
GROUP BY Vchrno
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN debit = 'BA11' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN credit LIKE 'PE%' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: @Vishnu Then add a `WHERE` clause which restricts to a certain date range.

Comment: Ya I added. Thanks I got the result

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
   select * from tablename
    where debit='BA11' and credite like 'PE%'
```

Comment: This would return zero records for the sample data given, when the OP appears to expect `JV1` to be in the result set.